# Flycheck and OpenMP pragmas for GCC

Tags: syntax-highlighting, flycheck

I'm using Flycheck with GCC as my checker for C. However, Flycheck gives warnings on OpenMP pragmas, regardless of whether they're correct or not! Is there any setting I can change to turn off these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [Flycheck 0.21](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/releases/flycheck-0.21.html) you can now use the new option `flycheck-gcc-openmp` to enable OpenMP in GCC for C and C++.

To enable OpenMP globally, add the following to your `init.el`:

```
(setq-default flycheck-gcc-openmp t)
```

I'd recommend to set this variable with [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) or [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables), for each file or project where you'd like to use OpenMP.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the Flycheck maintainer.